# useState does not update the value on Component Re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the following example, clicking the name change button does change the state, however that is not rendered on the UI.

The correct expected result is to change the name to **"Mike"**:

here is [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-khi4s?file=/src/index.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";


const useForm = initialValues => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  return [
    values,
    e => {
      console.log(e.target.value);
      setValues({
        ...values,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      });
    }
  ]
}

let count = 0;

const Hello = (props) => {
  console.log(`Hello.props: ${props.name} `)
  const [values, handleChange] = useForm({ nameInput: props.name });
  count++
  console.log(`RenderedAmount: ${values.nameInput} : ${count}`)
  return (
  <div>
    Name: <input value={values.nameInput} onChange={handleChange} name="nameInput" /><br/>
    Hello {values.nameInput}!
  </div>
);
}

const Container = (props) => {
  const [ name, setName] = useState(props.name);
  console.log(`Container: Name is ${name}`)
  return(
    <div>
      <Hello name={name}/>
      <button onClick={()=>{setName("Mike")}}>
        Change Name
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Container name="John"/>, rootElement);
```

Comment: I suspect the value of `e.target.name` is empty

Comment: `e.target.name` does not seem relevant, when {setName("Mike")} is called new props are created for `Hello` component and therefore should rerender the `Hello` component with the name "Mike"

Comment: As far as I have noticed, the problem lies in the `useState` of the useForm funciton. No matter what you get as initial values it will always return the old ones => "John"

Comment: Correct ...Iam not sure why it always returns the old value

Comment: I think it's because react saves the state and when you call useState it doesn't know that it should "recreate" the state, because it thinks nothing changed for the component => it will return the old state....I am trying to get around it right now but I haven't found a way yet

Comment: From the react docs "The initialState argument is the state used during the initial render. In subsequent renders, it is disregarded." ...that explains why it is giving the old value, however does not provide a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to know in order to get it working the way you want:

- For optimization purpose, React internally uses some techniques to minimize the number of DOM operations required to update the UI meaning that if you set the state to the old value again React will bail out on shouldComponentUpdate, and re-render is not going to happen. So if you set the state in your container component always to **"Mike"** it only causes the component to be re-rendered once until you set a different value.
- When using `useState` we can only initialize it with a value once by passing the value as a param on function call. so whenever the component re-renders, the props.name is not going to be set on useState function call.

  ```
  const [values, handleChange] = useForm({ nameInput: props.name });  // this only sets the initial value for the first time
  ```

  Usually in this situation you need to use `useEffect` hook (equivalent to componentDidMount) and set your state in there.
- Currently your `useForm` hook only updates the value through the DOM event, this makes it hard if we want to update the state outside of the DOM event. For example if we end up updating the useForm state in useEffect based on the value that we get from the prop then we need to be able to specify the field we want to update.

I believe this setup that you have is only for testing but based on what I explained above, below is what you could do in order to get it working.

**Updated your sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-xk3bm

```
const useForm = (initialValues) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  return [
    values,
    (newValue) => {
      setValues({
        ...values,
        ...newValue
      });
    }
  ];
};

let count = 0;

const Hello = (props) => {
  const [values, handleChange] = useForm({ "nameInput": props.name });
  useEffect(() => {
    handleChange({ "nameInput": props.name});
    // add props.name as a dependency 
    // so only update the nameInput if its value is changed
  }, [props.name])
  return (
    <div>
      Name:{" "}
      <input
        value={values.nameInput}
        onChange={({target}) => handleChange({"nameInput" : target.value})}
        name="nameInput"
      />
      <br />
      Hello {values.nameInput}!
    </div>
  );
};

const Container = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(props.name);
  return (
    <div>
      <Hello name={name} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          count++; // I'm incrementing the counter here to fool react to update the state with a new value. You will fix this however you want
          setName("Mike" + count);
        }}
      >
        Change Name To Mike #
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Container name="John" />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer by @Spring is better**

I came up with a very cheaty solution:

```js
// from the Hello component
const [values, handleChange] = useForm({ nameInput: props.name });
if (values.nameInput !== props.name) {
  handleChange({ target: { name: "nameInput", value: props.name } });
}
count++;
...
```

I am basically just checking if the returned state is outdated and setting it to the new value. This answer should not really be implemented like this, but I think you can work out a better solution with it.

Answer (score 0):

first add a function in your cutom hook that change state depending on directly passed values not input event as third params , the use

Here is a working [CodePen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-2zwfo)

custom hook shoudl look

```
const useForm = (initialValues) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  return [
    values,
    (e) => {
      console.log(e.target.value);
      setValues({
        ...values,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      });
    },
    (vals) => {
      setValues({
        ...values,
        ...vals
      });
    }
  ];
};
```

the useEffect hooks in your hello to watch props.name change , and use that cutom hooks third function to spred new values in state ,
also note that it should be named exactly as the sent initial values ( useform );

hello compnent add this last :

```
const Hello = (props) => {
   console.log(`Hello.props: ${props.name} `);
  //  hook with three param 
  const [values, handleChange, setValue] = useForm({ nameInput: props.name });
  // watch props.name change !
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue({ nameInput: props.name });
  }, [props.name]);
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: The `name=nameInput` is already there, please have a look at the code

Comment: you just added it , and now it works well !

Comment: no it does not please read the question. the button click does not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `props.name` instead of `values.nameInput` in the Hello function

State changes to render the component again. Property of component is changed in your case, so u need to use "prop"

Code : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-itk2r?file=/src/index.js:658-668

Comment: This makes the input field uneditable since it will rerender and use the old name again

Comment: Like MrCoding stated, this solution just creates another problem.

Answer (score -4):

This is because React hooks can only be called at the beggining of functional React components, that is to say, JS functions that return HTML (JSX) and their name  starts with a capital letter. In this case, you are calling `useState` on a function that is not a React Functional Component (line 8)

Comment: I'm downvoting this because 1) React hooks do *not* need to be called at the beginning of function components; 2) JSX is *not* HTML; 3) It is not required to start their names with a capital letter.